# How to configure AWS Route 53 domain to point to the godaddy hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-hosting, amazon-route53

I have a domain purchased in AWS, but I have my website hosted under godaddy.
basically I want myawsdomain.com to serve my.godaddydomain.com

Did anyone had a situation like this and able to configure DNS? Please help.

Comment: Are you looking for a 301 redirection?

Comment: not a redirection. I have a domain purchased in AWS and site hosted in godaddy. it is like the EC2 instance replaced by godaddy hosting.